# reordering bars in qplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have this data:

```
> result_Q1_data
     HARM              TYPE
834 96979           TORNADO
130  8428    EXCESSIVE HEAT
856  7461         TSTM WIND
170  7259             FLOOD
464  6046         LIGHTNING
275  3037              HEAT
153  2755       FLASH FLOOD
427  2064         ICE STORM
760  1621 THUNDERSTORM WIND
972  1527      WINTER STORM
```

And I want to make a bar plot. I am using this command:

```
qplot(TYPE,HARM,data=result_Q1_data,stat="identity",geom="bar", fill=EVTYPE)
```

and get this [plot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzKGAdm8Fi1bNHI2M3JPWFREZGc/edit?usp=sharing)

How can I make the same plot where the data would decrease on the plot and there would not be words on x axis or they would be vertical? (I'm not good at english yet, sorry for bad explanation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you to use ggplot function, but if you want to use qplot. You need to reorder the levels of factor TYPE and remove the labels of x axis.

```
result_Q1_data = data.frame(
    'id' = c(834, 130, 856, 170, 464, 275, 153, 427, 760, 972),
    'HARM' = c(96979, 8428, 7461, 7259, 6046, 3037, 2755, 2064, 1621, 1527),
    'TYPE' = factor(c('TORNADO', 'EXCESSIVE HEAT', 'TSTM WIND', 'FLOOD', 'LIGHTNING',
       'HEAT', 'FLASH FLOOD', 'ICE STORM', 'THUNDERSTORM WIND', 
       'WINTER STORM')))

result_Q1_data$TYPE = factor(result_Q1_data$TYPE, 
         levels = result_Q1_data$TYPE[order(result_Q1_data$HARM, decreasing=T)])

qplot(TYPE,HARM,data=result_Q1_data,stat="identity",geom="bar", fill=TYPE) + 
    theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: A "cleaner" way to reorder the levels would be `result_Q1_data$TYPE<-with(result_Q1_data, reorder(TYPE,-HARM))`

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped enormously!

Answer (score 1):

I would use `ggplot` instead of the `qplot` command. You can reorder the bars inside your `ggplot` function:

```
ggplot(result_Q1_data, aes(x=reorder(TYPE,-HARM), y=HARM, fill=reorder(TYPE,-HARM))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, vjust=0.5))
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Why don't the names beneath the bars match the names of the colors in the legend.

Comment: should probably use `fill=rev(reorder(TYPE,HARM))` for consistency (or do the reordering before calling `ggplot`)

Comment: @BenBolker For some reason `fill=rev(reorder(TYPE,HARM))` doesn't work, but `fill=reorder(TYPE,-HARM)` does.

Comment: it's because the fill assignment looks at the order of the levels, not the order of the vectors.